# PLSQL assignment and casting

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Right, a bit of background first....I have a oracle package that has the following:

```
g_variable    constant varchar(6):= pkg_sample.get_config_num('test');
```

The function above "get_config_num" retrieves the value as a integer value. This seems to work and return the correct value. However the value for 'test' retrieved is actually is a varchar, so it should not work. Running "pkg_sample.get_config_num('test')" against dual I get (null) but in the application it seems to display the correct value.

Am I correct to assume that because we have "constant varchar(6)" we are assigning its type (casting it) as a varchar so it is able to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently there are two implicit data type casts occurring -- one in the function and one in the assignment of the function's value to the constant.

I would be uncomfortable with this, and would prefer that a get_config_string procedure be used. A get_config_date would also be handy.